# SAPUI5 Preprocessing Binding

Tags: templates, sapui5

I'm using *XML Preprocessor template* in a table:

```
<template:repeat list="{meta>/table/toLayout/results}" var="control">
```

The initialization for the preprocessor looks like this:

```
    oModel.read("/ObjectSet",{
                urlParameters: {"$expand": "toLayout,toData,toHead"},
                success: function(oData){
                    var oMetaModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({"table" : oData});    
                sap.ui.view({
                    preprocessors: {
                        xml: {
                            models: {meta: oMetaModel}
                        }
                    },
                    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
                    viewName: "com.clc.pfucommon.component.table.view.Table",
                    async: true
                }).loaded().then(...)
```

And the generated JSONModel looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I want to repeat 3 times like the result of

> toLayout

but I seem to can't find the right binding to do the job for me.

Comment: (based on your JSONModel) should not the binding be meta>/table/results/0/toLayout?

Comment: well not quite, with the binding meta>/table/results/0/toLayout the repeat only works one time... 
but thanks to your comment I got the right way an if i add /results it works as it should